# google map v3 DirectionsRenderer.direction objects one of the property name is changing periodically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying a draggable directions google map. when i drag a way point is created and the directions_changed event is fired.

i use DirectionsRenderer.directions to save the way points in the database.

I parsed the names of the objects and properties and i got the following

> status: OK; routes: [object Object];
>   Jf: [object Object]; Xg: true;

In the above the object Jf is the one which is having the waypoints but periodically that name Jf is changing and making us hard to find which property holds the waypoints. I have a method to find that. but yet i want to know how to handle this.

> Jf: [object Object]; // here Jf is
>   changing periodically

I used firefox to debug the object using console.log.

Hope i have made it clear.

Comment: As I recall, the waypoints will be part of the `step`s of the `routes` object!

Comment: Yes you are right. We were debugging the routes array using console.log and i saw that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The waypoints will be part of the `step`s of the `routes` object.

Just one extra note, if order does matter for you then you need to keep an eye on the `waypoint_order` field **if** you used the `optimize:true` argument. Since this will return the optimized path. [Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints).

Comment: I haven't used order but may i know in what situations order will be useful. Is it like which way point was created first... or could you give me references for that? :)